# How to export object from js file and import the object in a css file?

Tags: javascript, css, import, export

I'm trying to pass an object from a JavaScript file into a CSS file. I want to pass an object that contains different color values like rgb(127, 127, 127) into a css file.

I'm currently passing each color one variable at a time using

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
  --variable_name,
  colorTheme.text8Color
);
```

where `colorTheme` is the object I eventually want to be able pass and `text8Color` is just one key inside of the `colorTheme` object.

Inside of the css file, I'm using `var(--variable_name)` to retrieve the variable.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do. If you mean you want to be able to access different properties of a JavaScript object inside of CSS (i.e., using property accessors), you can't. In other words, you can't do something like this in CSS: `var(--object.property)` or `var(--object[property])`. CSS variables are property/value only.

Comment: Hello, that's pretty much what I want to do. So there's no way I can export the object some other way?

Comment: Not really. The idea is that you can set a CSS variable from within JS, not get a JS variable from within CSS. There was some discussion about namespacing variables in the CSS preprocessor LESS (see https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1357), but it never took off to my knowledge. Of course, you can always just define CSS styles from within your JS and reference the object properties that way (e.g., `element.style = object[property]`). But you can't do it that way from within a separate stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful responses.